# Change or Delete text inside data-reactid child

Tags: jquery

English isn't my first language but I try my best, I hope you understand my question.

I'm trying to Change or delete some Text inside a div data-reactid with jQuery. I googled for quite some hours and tried much stuff but since I'm really inexperienced I just can't get it to work.
The best case scenarion I think would be If I would be able to just find the specific text on the page instead of searching for the div where it's in but I'm already quite lost.
This Would be the page in question https://albiononline.com/en/characterbuilder/solo-builds/view/67145

Here is some code of me trying to delete numbers in divs, the 1 and 2 is from another answer i found of something similar and the 3 is where i try to delete it but with the same structure of the real page where I try to actually change it. The numbers are just a placeholder, the goal is to change some actual text like "Tier 8" on the actual page.

```js
//somehow this works 
$('.build-item-details-list[data-reactid="1.$mainhand"]').parent().remove();


//and this does not
$('.build-item-details-list[data-reactid="0.2.1.5.0.4.2.1.$mainhand.0.0"]').parent().remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  1
  <div class="build-item-details-list" data-reactid="1.$mainhand"></div>
</div>
<div>
  2
  <div class="build-item-details-list" data-reactid="2.$mainhand"></div>
</div>

<div class="build-item-details-list" data-reactid=".0.2.1.5.0.4.2.1.$mainhand">
  <div data-reactid=".0.2.1.5.0.4.2.1.$mainhand.0">
    <div data-reactid=".0.2.1.5.0.4.2.1.$mainhand.0.0">
      3
      <div data-reactid=".0.2.1.5.0.4.2.1.$mainhand.0.1">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I think the solution is probably really easy but since I'm not into any programming and can barely make a html site I just can't find the solution.

Why I'm doing this? I'm trying to make a dark mode and change some unnessecary text.
I hope someone could help me out a bit with this.

Comment: Oh no I just saw I mistyped "inside" in the title but I can't edit it.

Comment: with `.parent().remove(); ` you are removing parent and everything inside it. What exactly are you trying to achieve, be more clear. Are you trying to remove just number 3, as a number or as a element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1-** `0.2.1.5.0.4.2.1.$mainhand.0.0` is not the same as `.0.2.1.5.0.4.2.1.$mainhand.0.0` you are missing the `.`

**2-**  when you have :  `<div class="build-item-details-list" data-reactid="1.$mainhand"></div>` CSS class `build-item-details-list` is on same element as `data-reactid` so you need write your CSS selector in Jquery like this:

```
$('.build-item-details-list[data-reactid="xxx"]')
```

Notice the class and `data-reactid` are connected together.

What you are trying to do is find **a child** of `build-item-details-list` with some data attribute, they are not on same level, so you need to use different CSS selector: `.build-item-details-list * [data-reactid=` like this:

```
$('.build-item-details-list * [data-reactid=".0.2.1.5.0.4.2.1.$mainhand.0.0"]').parent().remove();
```

Notice the space and `*`.

**Please learn more about:**  [CSS selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

Keep in mid also your method is removing parent element and all elements inside it. Please use your DEV tools to see if this is what you even want:

**Example:**

```js
//and this does not
$('.build-item-details-list * [data-reactid=".0.2.1.5.0.4.2.1.$mainhand.0.0"]').parent().remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  1
  <div class="build-item-details-list" data-reactid="1.$mainhand"></div>
</div>
<div>
  2
  <div class="build-item-details-list" data-reactid="2.$mainhand"></div>
</div>

<div class="build-item-details-list" data-reactid=".0.2.1.5.0.4.2.1.$mainhand">
  <div data-reactid=".0.2.1.5.0.4.2.1.$mainhand.0">
    <div data-reactid=".0.2.1.5.0.4.2.1.$mainhand.0.0">
      3
      <div data-reactid=".0.2.1.5.0.4.2.1.$mainhand.0.1">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you want to delete / change just text inside div you should use `.text()` or `.html()`

```
$('.build-item-details-list * [data-reactid=".0.2.1.5.0.4.2.1.$mainhand.0.0"]').html("test");
```

**Example:**

```js
//and this does not
$('.build-item-details-list * [data-reactid=".0.2.1.5.0.4.2.1.$mainhand.0.0"]').html("test");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  1
  <div class="build-item-details-list" data-reactid="1.$mainhand"></div>
</div>
<div>
  2
  <div class="build-item-details-list" data-reactid="2.$mainhand"></div>
</div>

<div class="build-item-details-list" data-reactid=".0.2.1.5.0.4.2.1.$mainhand">
  <div data-reactid=".0.2.1.5.0.4.2.1.$mainhand.0">
    <div data-reactid=".0.2.1.5.0.4.2.1.$mainhand.0.0">
      3
      <div data-reactid=".0.2.1.5.0.4.2.1.$mainhand.0.1">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey thanks this really helped me out! it's working an the last snippet with the .html is pretty much exactly what I need. I really appreciate your help this was driving me insane. I will take a good look at the CSS selectors :)